# console connection via Cisco router's AUX port

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios

my question is simple: if I am logged into a Cisco router via console or ethernet in priviledged mode, is there a command to initiate a connection through the local AUX port to a nearby console port of another router/switch?

(alternatively, could I accomplish this if I configured reverse telnet on the local router and then type the command "telnet local_loopbackIP 2xxx" port?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just telnet to a local (up) interface using port 2001.  Aux 0 is (always?) line 1.

```
int loopback0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
line aux 0
 transport input all
 transport output all
```

Telnet 192.168.1.1 2001.

Comment: `show line` to find the tty for *aux*. In one case, mine is 161.

Comment: Thanks, Ricky.  I was trying to find an example (on my gear) where the aux was something other than line 1.  What platform has it as line 161?