# Can I connect to Cisco router's AUX port from a switch Ethernet port?

Tags: cisco, switch, router, ethernet, cisco-ios

I know from this question [console connection via Cisco router's AUX port](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/console-connection-via-cisco-routers-aux-port?newreg=ff83efb925a5444e87a3be5672134b71)
that it's possible to connect from a Cisco router to the switch/router's console port but I would like to know if it's possible to do the opposite way.

i.e: Can I connect to Cisco (2600 series) router's AUX port from a switch Ethernet port?

What I would like is to be able to access my router trough it's AUX port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AUX port is basically a serial port and is not an Ethernet port at all, so no you can't connect it to an ethernet switch port.

But you can connect a RTC modem to it and access the console remotely by dial-in.

Answer (score 0):

As per Cisco :
The console and auxiliary ports on Cisco IOS routers are `asynchronous serial ports`. The console port and the auxiliary port are configured as data terminal equipment (DTE). For Cisco 1000, 1600, 2500, 2600, and 3600 Series Routers, the console and auxiliary ports both use RJ-45 connectors. Adapters are available for connections to PC terminals, modems, or other external communications equipment.